# Posting Multiple Photo as one batch to facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I need help. i have a group of photos ususally selected from the database. I loop around an array say $piclinks then look around it to post the pictures. But i need it to display as one post as shown in the image[image: Exactly how i want the pics to appear on facebook page].

Those any one have an idea what i can do

```
 <?php


    define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__.'/src/Facebook/');
require_once(__DIR__.'/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
         'app_id' => '2082153322064454',
         'app_secret' => '7355d8111164630537a35b43a1bbd336',
         'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
        ]);

        $piclinks = array("http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/agydwb6_460s.jpg", "https://greenparrotnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Boss-Mustapha.jpg");
        foreach($piclinks as $selectedlink){

        //Post property to Facebook
            $linkData = [
             'message' => 'Your message here',
             'url' => $selectedlink
            ];
            $pageAccessToken ='EAAdltRkhKkYBAHbLBwoKDZBSat5ulIJZBbMz4gZBQSZCZCY7oH7vRgN16QBuYZBZAjSzZCvt04ypoRaTG4o5jdhXA9bjIV8ZB0ZAJ8lsVNZBxYRInwn7tc8ZBsmdhxKZBnmHCA0n3k3wOOlQRcpDPQyXa1RZBoSb3ZAasDhHHxQfTeRdPObE68OZAAxMoaDcs';


            try {
             $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
             echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
             exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
             echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
             exit;
            }
            $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
            echo 'done';

            }

?>
```

Comment: So what is your actual, specific question now? You know basic language constructs like _loops_, right?

Comment: sure...looking at the code....where do i loop? the  $linkData or  $response. am barely trying to get a work around. if u have a help offer it. if i did not have need for it i will not post sir

Comment: Well if you want to post individual link data each time, then around both, obviously?

Comment: Than CBroe...i will edit that code shortly to sure how i implemented the loop. but it posts as different new post. i need it to post as group of pictres posted once

Comment: This is a more complex issue than you might think; there is no direct way to achieve this AFAIK. If you just upload single photos like this, then it is up to Facebook to group those pictures (like in one of those “Page foobar has uploaded x new photos” pseudo posts.) I have heard people talking about uploading the photos first (parameter set not to create a feed story), and then making a real post afterwards, that has those uploaded images specified as attachments ... but I don’t know if that still works.

Comment: thank you CBroe. i will keep searching for options. i know it can be done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171628/discussion-between-legendchyke-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 2):

You have to upload your photos first, then you will get photo id. After that you have to create post with all photo ids. It may be helpful for you. Example code:

```
$images = []; // say your all images is in array.
foreach($images as $image){
    try {
        $response = $fb->post("/PAGEID/photos", [
            'source' =>  $fb->fileToUpload($image),
            'published' => 'false'
        ], PAGE_TOKEN);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        $errors[]= 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    $post_images[]= $graphNode['id'];
}

foreach ($post_images as $key => $post_image) {
    $attachMedia[$key] = ['media_fbid' => $post_image];
}

try {
    $response = $fb->post(
        "/PAGEID/feed",
        [
            'message' => YOUR_MESSAGE,
            'attached_media' => $attachMedia
        ],
        PAGE_TOKEN

    );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    $errors[]= 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$post = json_decode($response->getBody());
```